# C# TableLayoutPanel - 2nd row content not displayed

Tags: c#, forms, user-controls, tablelayoutpanel

I have a user control that displays an object. This user control is composed of :

```
- A main TableLayoutPanel with 2 rows to separate things in two parts
    - A nested TableLayoutPanel containing a "header"
        - A label for the name of the object
        - Several buttons...
    - A second nested TableLayoutPanel containing the members of the object
        - Dynamically added user controls...
```

All these controls, rows and columns are in AutoSize mode.

This user control that represents an object is initialized based on a JSON file. The children (i.e properties of the JSON object) are added dynamically into the second nested TableLayoutPanel.

I'm not going to provide the whole code because it would be too long to read, but children are added this way :

```
propertiesTableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(memberView, 0, propertiesTableLayoutPanel.RowCount - 1);
++propertiesTableLayoutPanel.RowCount;
```

Basically I always keep an empty row. When adding a child, I put it into this empty row and then create another empty row by incrementing the row count. I do this in order to copy the style of the row when I add a new one, though I'm not sure this is actually needed.

**My problem is that, for some unknown reason, the 2nd child user control (index = 1) is never displayed.** And it's always the second one. The row is displayed, but it seems to be empty. The first one (index = 0) and the following ones (index > 2) are displayed properly.

I have made sure by debugging and logging that **all the children user controls are properly placed within the second nested TableLayoutPanel, and that their Visible property is set to true**, but it doesn't seem to be enough.

Am I missing something about styles or anything ? Thank you.

**EDIT** : Might have to do something with the RowStyles, and probably the row height. Seems like there are already two row styles when I only have one row, which is strange.

**EDIT** : Seems like row height is not used when using AutoSize mode anyway.

Comment: See this other question of mine which seems to fix the problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37808238/c-sharp-tablelayoutpanel-2nd-row-content-not-displayed However i'm not sure this is the right solution so i'll just put this asa comment.

Answer (score 0):

Fix here : stackoverflow.com/questions/37808238/
Was due to garbage left by the designer. An extra RowStyle that shouldn't have been there and that can safely be removed manually.

Comment: That is link for this own question, I think you want to refer to this instead https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37809965