# TableLayoutPanel - Designer generates an unexpected absolute RowStyle

Tags: c#, forms, tablelayoutpanel

I have a user control that contains a TableLayoutPanel which initially contains a single row and a single column. Everything is in AutoSize mode.

The code generated by the designer is the following :

```
        // 
        // propertiesTableLayoutPanel
        // 
        this.propertiesTableLayoutPanel.AutoSize = true;
        this.propertiesTableLayoutPanel.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
        this.propertiesTableLayoutPanel.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Control;
        this.propertiesTableLayoutPanel.ColumnCount = 1;
        this.propertiesTableLayoutPanel.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle());
        this.propertiesTableLayoutPanel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(67, 37);
        this.propertiesTableLayoutPanel.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(67, 0, 5, 0);
        this.propertiesTableLayoutPanel.Name = "propertiesTableLayoutPanel";
        this.propertiesTableLayoutPanel.RowCount = 1;
        this.propertiesTableLayoutPanel.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle());
        this.propertiesTableLayoutPanel.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Absolute, 1F));
        this.propertiesTableLayoutPanel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(0, 0);
        this.propertiesTableLayoutPanel.TabIndex = 1;
        this.propertiesTableLayoutPanel.Visible = false;
```

I Can't understand why there is an absolute style that is added. This seems to be causing me some problems elsewhere.

Why is this absolute RowStyle added ? Is the designer going to regenerated this line of code if I delete it manually ? Thank you.

**EDIT** : I removed this designer-generated line manually and it fixed all my problems. The designer doesn't seem to regenerate it. However I would still like to know if this is just a garbage left by the designer that is safe to remove if or not.

Comment: Mishaps like this tend to be explained by getting an exception at design-time.  Such exceptions can leave quite a mess and just about nobody remembers seeing them because they are usually cryptic and quickly clicked away.  Repairing the damage like you did is just fine, best to move on with some extra attention to getting cryptic message boxes perhaps.

Comment: @HansPassant Okay thanks for your help. I can remember seing a few "Invalid property value", sometimes for no clear reason and that just don't occur again after restarting Visual Studio.